# How do I set DefaultDirName in an Inno setup from an ini file?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to pull the DefaultDirName infomration out of an ini file in the windows directory, how whould I do this?

Answer (score 5):

you can also do.

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={ini:Filename,Section,Key|DefaultValue}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use following code in `[code]` section to get string from INI file (in example: [InstallSettings] section, variable name: DefDirName):

```
[code]
function GetDefDirName(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := GetIniString('InstallSettings', 'DefDirName', '', 'c:\your_app_dir\file_with_info.ini'));
end;
```

and, at the very top of script in `[Setup]` section:

```
DefaultDirName={code:GetDefDirName}
```